# Badge overflow on users with too many badges

Tags: bug, design, user-card

When a user has "too much" reputation and "too many" badges, the design of the user card breaks:

> [image: user card with overflow]

The badge counters overflowing to another line.

Can anything be done about this?

For example, expanding the rep and badges to their own lines:

> Name
> Rep
> Badges

Comment: He is not the only such user. There are at least 5 users with >100 golden badges, >1k silver badges, >1k bronze badges, >100k rep.

Comment: This issue also plays here on MSE, especially with former staff member Shog9. Your still missed...

Comment: This is still an issue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOuSN.png

Answer (score 18):

A line break isn't a big deal, but it would be better if the number were bound to the badge icon, breaking the line before the bronze badge marker instead of after.  When displaying badge counts, treat it as three elements (each of which has two parts) instead of six.

A comment suggests rounding to thousands and using "k", as is done with reputation, but that's just kicking the can down the road -- once Jon has 10k bronze badge (later this year?), you'd still have too many characters to fit in one line.  And if not then, then surely when he reaches 10k silver a little later.  Just eyeballing it, "* 460 * 10k * 10k" doesn't look like would fit in the space currently occupied by "* 460 * 6195 *".

Better to just resign yourself to line wrap and then make that line wrap work better.

Either that, or make the space a little wider.  The problem doesn't occur on the Users list:

[image: Jon Skeet's entry on Users page]

Comment: If both silver and gold were turned to "K"... I don't think this would be an issue until he hits 100K. Depends on if they decimalize or not (6k vs 6.2k). Do we know what the character limit is?

Comment: Let's just suspend the guy until 2025 and be done with it ...

Comment: @Catija I'm just eyeballing it. "o 460 o 10k o 10k" doesn't look like it fits in the same space as "o 460 o 6195 o" (from the screen shot).

Comment: Right, but the wrap could be caused by a single digit, so there may be three extra digits there that you can't "see".

Comment: @Catija oh, I see what you're saying.  Yeah, I don't know how to check that; might have to ask a designer.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Why not allowing block to stretch? In current case 5px would be enough. Why don't we remove this line breaks? We have enough space to make user info block wider.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov it looks like they fixed it somehow (see update).

Comment: @MonicaCellio No it's not fixed (a least on question pages). Open [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s any answer on StackOverflow and you'll see that his badge overflows.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov oh, I didn't notice that the question was specifically about *posts*.  I wonder why the two representations are different.